# Unit testing with a mock HttpListener

Tags: c#, httplistener

I should say that I'm fairly new in the mock-framework world of C#. I'm building a small service that listens to incoming HTTP requests using a [`System.Net.HttpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.HttpListener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and would like to unit test my implementation by injecting a mock instance of that class. So I tried using [Moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/), but that of course requires that the mock target is an interface so that it can provide a stub implementation. Then I tried using Microsoft Fakes, but it won't let me generate a `StubHttpListener`. So is there any other way to mock the behaviour of `System.Net.HttpListener`?

Answer (score 3):

Write a class that wraps the HttpListener and extract an interface from that then you can mock/stub your wrapper

Answer (score 1):

1. Create custom interface contains used by service methods of HttpListener
2. Create own class derived from HttpListener and implements interface from p.1 using HttpListener methods calls
3. Pull interface from p.1 in service class (using IoC or other mechanics) and map dependency injection to custom class from p.2
4. Mock custom interface from p.1 to unit test the service

Comment: `HttpListener` and related classes (`HttpListenerContext`, `HttpListenerRequest` and `HttpListenerResponse`) are sealed.